# using columns in beamer class with formula and figures

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to create a slide of a presentation with the beamer class. On this slide, I would like to display some formulas in the left column and some figures on the right. The Problem is that the size of the formulas/equations is too big. Therefore, only half the figure is on the slide, the other does not fit on the slide. I can't figure out how to decrease the size of the formula. I included all the packages that I use because I made the experience that this kind of errors is sometimes produced by a specific combination of packages that should not be used together.

If I change

```
  \begin{column}{0.1\textwidth}
```

to

```
  \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
```

then nothing happens. I also tried using Environments as "small" around the "align"-environment, but it did not change anything either.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{Fabry-Perot Cavity}
  \begin{columns}[T]
  \begin{column}{0.1\textwidth}
  \begin{align*}
  E_{transmitted}&=E_0 t_1 t_2 \exp(-i \omega L/ c)+E_0 t_1 t_2 r_1 r_2\exp    (-i \omega 3L/ c)+\dots\\
&=E_0 t_1 t_2 \exp(-i \omega L/ c)\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\left[r_1 r_2 \exp(-i \omega 2L/ c)\right ]^l\\
&=E_0\frac{t_1 t_2 \exp(-i \omega L c)}{1-r_1 r_2 \exp(-i \omega 2 L /c)} \\
 I_{transmitted}&= |E_0|^2 \frac{t_1^2t_2^2}{1+r_1^2 r_2^2 -2 r_1 r_2 \cos(2 \omega L/c)}
 \end{align*}
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{0.1\textwidth}
 \begin{figure}[!ht] 
 \def\svgwidth{200pt}    
 \input{FabryPerot.pdf_tex}  
 \end{figure}
 \end{column}
 \end{columns}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File 'FabryPerot.pdf_tex' not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Above frame is obtained by use of `multlined` environment from package `mathtools`, reduced font size to `\small`, instead `\exp` use `\mathrm{e}^{...}` and use of `\MoveEqLeft` in formatting of equations:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Fabry-Perot Cavity}
    \begin{columns}%[T]
\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
\small
    \begin{align*}
    \MoveEqLeft
E_{\mathrm{transmitted}}      \\ 
& = \begin{multlined}[t]
        E_0 t_1 t_2 \,\mathrm{e}^{(-i \omega L/ c)}    \\[1ex]
      + E_0 t_1 t_2 r_1 r_2 \,\mathrm{e}^{(-i \omega 3L/ c)} + \dots  
    \end{multlined}\\
& = E_0 t_1 t_2 \,\mathrm{e}^{(-i \omega L/ c)}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}
        \left[r_1 r_2 \,\mathrm{e}^{(-i \omega 2L/ c)}\right ]^l   \\
& = E_0\frac{t_1 t_2  \,\mathrm{e}^{(-i \omega L c)}}
            {1-r_1 r_2 \,\mathrm{e}^{(-i \omega 2 L /c)}}
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
    \MoveEqLeft
I_{\mathrm{transmitted}}      \\
& = |E_0|^2 \frac{t_1^2t_2^2}{1+r_1^2 r_2^2 -2 r_1 r_2 \cos(2 \omega L/c)}
    \end{align*}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
% \def\svgwidth{200pt}
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}%\input{FabryPerot.pdf_tex}
    \end{figure}
\end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This works. Why doesn't changing the size of the column effect the actual size of the column, e.g. changing \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth} to \begin{column}{0.1\textwidth}?

Comment: column width `0.1\textwidth` is not realistic ... image is to small (if it is accommodated to column width), equation protrude right column border ... as you can see from code, to shrinking equation to close of column width more tricks is used (from reducing font size, new form of writing exponent function, broke lone lines into two ...). Consequence of your column selection you can observe with simple test, however.